# Ruby language curious integer arithmetic : (-5/2) != -(5/2)

Tags: ruby, integer

I spent some time on a quite simple task about splitting an array. Until I found that: `2 == 5/2` and `-3 == -5/2`. To get `-2` I need to pull the minus out of the parentheses: `-2 == -(5/2)`. Why does this happen? 
As I understand it, the result rounds to the smallest integer, but `(-2.5).to_i == -2`.  Very curious.

```
# https://www.codewars.com/kata/swap-the-head-and-the-tail/train/ruby
# -5/2 != -(5/2)
def swap_head_tail a
  a[-(a.size/2)..-1] + a[a.size/2...-(a.size/2)] + a[0...a.size/2] 
end
```

Comment: It's about the rounding rules.  It rounds *down*. So 2.5 rounds down to 2 because 2 is *smaller* than 2.5. -2.5 rounds down to -3 because -3 is *smaller* than -2.5. Thus, -5/2 is -2.5 which rounds to -3. -(5/2) is -(2) since 5/2 = 2.5 rounds down to 2 and then, because of the parentheses, the minus is applied.

Comment: @lurker so `Fixnum#to_i` works differently? It just cuts the fractional part, while when divide we move to the smaller integer. Hm... interesting.

Comment: Yes. According to the documentation for [`Float.to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Float.html#method-i-to_i) it *truncates*, it does not round. Your question is a good one. It's not clear from the `Integer` class documentation what happens when you take one `Integer` divided by another `Integer`.

Comment: @lurker: It is, however, specified in the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) specification.

Comment: @JörgWMittag indeed. Thank you for citing that reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

It's not quite clear what kind of answer your are looking for other than [because that is how it is specified](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## 15.2.8.3.4 `Integer#/`
>
> `/(`*other*`)`
>
> - *Visibility*: public
> - *Behavior*:
>
>   - a) If *other* is an instance of the class `Integer`:
>
>     - 1) If the value of *other* is *0*, raise a direct instance of the class `ZeroDivisionError`.
>     - 2) Otherwise, let *n* be the value of the receiver divided by the value of *other*. Return an instance of the class `Integer` **whose value is the largest integer smaller than or equal to *n***.
>         NOTE The behavior is the same even if the receiver has a negative value. **For example, `-5 / 2` returns `-3`**.

As you can see, the specification even contains your exact example.

It is also specified in [the Ruby/Spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/integer/divide_spec.rb#L19-L21):

> ```
> it "supports dividing negative numbers" do
>   (-1 / 10).should == -1
> end
> ```

Compare this with the specification for `Float#to_i` (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## 15.2.9.3.14 `Float#to_i`
>
> `to_i`
>
> - *Visibility*: public
> - *Behavior*: The method returns an instance of the class `Integer` whose value is **the integer part of the receiver**.

And in [the Ruby/Spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/float/shared/to_i.rb#L2):

> ```
> it "returns self truncated to an Integer" do
>   899.2.send(@method).should eql(899)
>   -1.122256e-45.send(@method).should eql(0)
>   5_213_451.9201.send(@method).should eql(5213451)
>   1.233450999123389e+12.send(@method).should eql(1233450999123)
>   -9223372036854775808.1.send(@method).should eql(-9223372036854775808)
>   9223372036854775808.1.send(@method).should eql(9223372036854775808)
> end
> ```